# Avalonia - how to create new window?

Tags: c#, avalonia

I'm trying to get familiar with Avalonia, and porting one of my projects to it.

I have a problem with creating new windows - I use manual from [Tutorial](https://avaloniaui.net/docs/quickstart/window#visual-studio), and get just .xaml.cs file in my Solution Explorer:
[image]

File AboutView.xaml is created in project folder, contains

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
    x:Class="MyProjectName.Views.AboutView"
    Title="AboutView">
Welcome to Avalonia!
```

but not shown. AboutView.xaml.cs contains the following code, and shows error:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by switching to the file system (or something similar) in the explorer, and finding the file with the *.csproj* extension. I removed this configuration section and the problem disappeared:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="Views\AdditionalWindow.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
</ItemGroup>
```